# How to know if i click any link in drupal and set a variable?

Tags: forms

I need some help for the following case:

In my content-type i have a cck link that redirect to another page.
So, i need do this:

When, i click in the link.. In my content-type_form ([name_content_type]_node_form) i need to extract a variable of this form of my node:

`form_state['values']['id'] = $id; 
variable_set($id, 1);`

Then, when i stay in the another page (that is a form) ; in this form do:

```
$form['id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => variable_get($id, 1)
);
```

for view the corresponding id.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you need to pass a value via the URL, and fix a forms element based on this.

You have to output a link ith your variable in it, in the form yoursite.com?variable=value, preferably via the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/6) function.

On your second page, the value will be accessible in several ways, for example in the $_GET variable.

More powerfull and Drupalish, you could also implement a [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu/6) to be able to use clean URLs like yoursite.com/some_menu_entry/yourvalue and the corresponding function.

Comment: also realize that `variable_set()` is going to reset any caching for that page as well.

Comment: And furthermore, it won't be session dependant, so it will change value depending on the last user who accessed the page. Bottomline : variable_set is not adapted for this case.

Comment: @Countzero So, i'm not using the function variable_set variable_get for this case... Only i get the value by $_GET.

Comment: @Countzero that work fine :D